# @Vaild of javax.validation.Valid does not work. No exception occurred

Tags: spring, bean-validation, spring-validator

I use @Valid annotation but not works. There are no exception.
 i add all needed maven repositories but resuls is same.

here are my POJO class (Offer.java) :

```
package com.geno.springmvctut.dao;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Offer {

private int id;

@Size(min = 5, max = 100, message = "@Valid works!")
private String name;

private String email;
private String text;

public Offer() { }

public Offer(String name, String email, String text) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.text = text;
}

public Offer(int id, String name, String email, String text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.text = text;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}


}
```

and OffersController.java:

```
package com.geno.springmvctut.controller;

import com.geno.springmvctut.dao.Offer;
import com.geno.springmvctut.service.OffersService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;


@Controller
@Component
public class OffersController {

private OffersService offersService;

public OffersService getOffersService() {
    return offersService;
}

@Autowired
public void setOffersService(OffersService offersService) {
    this.offersService = offersService;
}

@RequestMapping("/createOffer")
public String createOffer(){
    return "createOffer";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/doCreate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doCreate(Model model, @Valid Offer offer, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()){

        System.out.println("Validation failed");
        List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();

        for (ObjectError error : errors){
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Successful validation");
    }
    return "offerCreated";
}
}
```

syntax of this code is correct but logically not works. result always is

> Successful validation

whatever i do ... so anybody has any idea how to fix it? who can help me? 
thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you test the method ? The curl or whatever ?

Comment: I use form submitting. when form action attribute is "doCreate"

Comment: I don't see any trouble with this code ... Except for the "Model" parameter, it looks like spring boot 2 tutorials... Can you try without the Model parameter ? Can you show us the maven file juste in case ?

Comment: I have removed Model parameter but result is same.

Comment: pom.xml 

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/ejb3-persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: maven file is correctly filled

Comment: These are very old spring versions. Try with spring boot as described in https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: I think you need to add **@RequestBody** before @Valid. Try  call your service using postman, and ensure you are violating the validation in your request body.